# get amazon web service unsigned URLs in c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, unsigned

I m using amazon sdk for .net 
 i have uploaded a file in folder of my bucket , now i want to get the url of that file using this code

```
 GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest();
        request.BucketName = "my-new-bucket2";
        request.Key = "Images/Tulips.jpg";
        request.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
        request.Protocol = Protocol.HTTP;
        string url = s3.GetPreSignedURL(request);
```

but this is returning url with key , exipration date and signature but infact i want to get the url without them , there is no other method to get the url

**Things i tried **

i search and found that i have to change permission of my file

i have change the permission of file while uploading

```
request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
```

but still its returning the same url 
http://my-new-bucket2.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Images/Tulips.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxxxx&Expires=1432715743&Signature=xxxxxxxxxxx%3D

it work when i remove keyid ,expire and signature 
but how can i get url with out it , or do i have to do it manually

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. If you know the bucket name and the key then you have everything you need to construct the URL. As an example, here bucketname is `yourbucketname` and the key is `this/is/your/key.jpg`.

https://yourbucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/this/is/your/key.jpg

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I just browsed their documentation and was not able to find a method to return an absolute url. However, I really believe there is one that I could not see. For now, you can solve your problem by extracting an absolute url from the result you have:

```
GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest();
        request.BucketName = "my-new-bucket2";
        request.Key = "Images/Tulips.jpg";
        request.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
        request.Protocol = Protocol.HTTP;
        string url = s3.GetPreSignedURL(request);
        index = url.IndexOf("?");
if (index > 0)
   string absUrl = url.Substring(0, index);
```

Hope it helps :)